# Translation of "That is nothing to be proud of."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate this sentence?

> That is nothing to be proud of.

I can only think of

> (a) Das ist nichts, auf dem man stolz sein soll.

Are there better ways to translate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good and fluid translation would be

> Das ist nichts, worauf man stolz sein sollte.

The subjunctive is crucial here because this is your own/ society's opinion. Using the indicative mode is impolite - if you are not talking to a child that has done something rude.

Your translation would be fine, too, but make sure to use the subjunctive and use the accusative instead of dative.

> Das ist nichts, auf das man stolz sein sollte.

Until now, I presumed that your sentence is meant to critizise someone. If I am not mistaken, it could also express a humble self-critique. In this case, *könnte* instead of *sollte* would be better.

Comment: Thanks, dervonnebenaan! Is there any difference between using `worauf` and `auf das`? Can we use `worauf` only because the noun is `nichts` and not with other usual nouns?

Comment: @Mika H. we got a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language-and-usage) for such questions ;) Also the answer to this might get bigger than you expect. I suggest you just ask a new question

Comment: Vogel612 is right, this is worth being asked in a new question. I actually have no quick answer for that.

Answer (score -1):

In Yiddish we have the following idiomatic expression

> "Das is nischts, auf was zu stolzieren."

Note that in German the general meaning of *stolzieren* is lost. It is only used in the context of walking (*"strutting"*).

Answer (score -3):

More idiomatic is "Das ist kein Grund zum Stolz."

German loves nominalization, and in this case it's actually shorter and sweeter.

Comment: Nun denn so sei es: Als Ergebnis einer ausschweifenden Diskussion: "Das ist kein Grund zum Stolz" is certainly not `more idiomatic` or `sweeter` than the answer from dervonnebenan, in fact it is neither idiomatic nor sweet. Instead one could say: *"[...] Grund stolz zu sein"*. The currently posted sentence will most certainly not be used by a native german speaker. please edit your answer accordingly ;) greets  Em1, falkb, Vogel612

Comment: also, I think the statement that German loves nominalization is ... well... not true. A certain style might, but as far as spoken German goes people prefer the verb over the noun. English with its gerund... that is a language that loves nominalzation. German with all its dependent sentences ... not so much